Is private Github a way to prove code ownership?
I am currently working about 2 years on my own for a big (this is my estimation) project.
I would like to find the best way in order to have a proof that the code is mine.
I mean about the case that somebody steals the code, I would like to have a proof about who wrote the code.
Is a private Github project and the commits in specific days a proof in a court?
Or else what is the best way to secure something like this?
I tried to find the best solution with google search but didn't found the specific answer

@JiminyCricket. I suspect that users here will not agree that this is the correct site. Because it is written as a first-person request for how to deal with a specific situation OP is currently facing, users are likely to close it as a request for specific legal advice.

@bdb484 Apologies on that. We've the same requirement on the biology/medical etc. sites that questions should not be personalized.

It's worth noting that it's very easy to create commits with falsified author and date information and upload them to GitHub. I don't know if GitHub provides any mechanism for seeing who actually uploaded the commits and when.

So Github is not a legit proof of having the code at a specific date?
What could be a legit proof?
One suggested to send a sealed envelope with the code and not open it until an assuming court to take place.
One other suggested to give the code to a notary. But then there is a probability that the code leaks from the employees there.

if I have some backups of the code in different dates over the years is this a proof for the court?
I mean in backup disks

It's even more trivial to falsify dates on backup disks, regardless of the media used.  Strictly speaking, this isn't a problem unique to computer code, but any creative work.

This question is similar to: How do you prove a fact at issue in litigation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Nikic233 If you're really concerned about it, you can keep your own private design documents stored elsewhere (e.g. written on paper, word documents, etc.). Writing on paper may have some advantages -- most people won't go through the trouble of snatching your paper documents and digitizing them, for example. Also, there are forensic methods that can be used to estimate when a document was written with ink. But most likely the biggest advantage is that writing things by hand has a learning advantage (which has no legal benefit, but it will probably strengthen your engineering design).

england-and-wales
Proving a fact in court generally means convincing the judge (or jury) that the probability of the fact being true exceeds some threshold. This is known as the "standard of proof". For civil cases the standard of proof is generally "on the balance of probabilities" which means that it is >50% likely that the fact is true.
There is usually not any one thing that is required to prove a fact. What's important is that your set of evidence is more convincing than your opponent's set of evidence. If you can show that you uploaded your code to Github on a specific date, and your opponent's only evidence is that they uploaded the code a month later, then you may have proved your case. If your opponent can additionally show evidence that they emailed a copy of the code to a friend the previous year, then you may have failed to prove your case.
Having a Github commit on a given date doesn't prove that you wrote the code. It's merely evidence that might support such an assertion. Someone else could have written it and then you uploaded it. Ideally it should be just one item of evidence out of a set which, taken together, is as convincing as possible.

Part of the point here is that the fundamental evidence is your testimony under oath that you wrote the code. All the rest is just supporting evidence to back up your testimony.  In the absence of any claim otherwise your bare word is sufficient evidence.

@PaulJohnson If there weren't conflicting claims, this wouldn't be an issue in the first place. So the question is how to back up your claim.
